# Circle tangent to three tangent circles (without the Soddy/Descartes formula)

Tags: geometry, circles, soddy-circles

> We have three circles tangent to each other with radii $1$, $2$, and $3$. Another circle is tangent to the other circles; find the radius of that circle using elementary geometry, without the [Soddy Circles formula (aka, Descartes' Theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem).

[image]

My Attempt: I tried to draw a triangle with points $A$, $B$, and $C$, and then I proved that one of its angles is $90^\circ$.

Comment: I can proof that it is right angle but I want to find radii of small circle

Comment: Your proof is false: immagine the three outer circles had the same radius, $ABC$ becomes an equilateral triangle.

Comment: OP is right because the radius are given as $1,2,3$ which makes $3,4,5$ triangle.

Comment: Yes that's what I exactly want to say.

Comment: Do you want a solution using coordinate geometry but without quoting Descartes' Theorem?

Comment: Yes you  can only use simple geometry

Comment: But do you mean coordinate geometry is OK or not?

Comment: Yes that's  okey.

Comment: Our teacher told that it can solved by pythagoras theorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have observed, $AB$ and $AC$ are perpendicular, so take $A$ as the origin and assign coordinates $B(4,0)$ and $C(0,3)$.

Let the centre of the inner circle be at $(a,b)$ and the radius is $r$. Then, considering distances, the following equations apply:

$$a^2+b^2=(1+r)^2$$
$$(a-4)^2+b^2=(3+r)^2$$
$$a^2+(b-3)^2=(2+r)^2$$

Subtracting the first equation from the second gives rise to $$a=\frac{2-r}{2}$$
Subtracting the first equation from the third gives rise to $$b=\frac{3-r}{3}$$

Substituting these into the first equation then leads to the quadratic equation $$23r^2+132r-36=0$$

The roots are $$r=\frac{6}{23}$$ which is the answer you are looking for, and $$-6$$ which corresponds to the radius $6$ of the outer kissing circle. All of this can be verified by applying Descartes' Formula.